# How to calculate average of values between blank cells in a single column?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a dataset containing several columns (A, D, G....etc). Each column contains blocks of data that are separated by single blank cells (A2-A14, A16-A28, A30-A.... etc). These blocks of data each have a different number of cells within them. I have been trying to find a way to calculate the average and standard deviation of each of the blocks by dragging the formulas, but can't figure it out. Any ideas?

[excel data screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1nPDH.png)

Comment: If this range is always under 100 then use =average(A2:A100) if the data starts in cell A2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can try the following formula in `B2`:

For `AVERAGE`:

```
=AVERAGE((INDEX(A:A,ROW()):INDEX(A:A,MATCH(TRUE,INDEX(ISBLANK(INDEX(A:A,ROW()):A$10000),),0)+ROW()-1)))
```

Then copy and paste the formula in the other yellow Average cells. The formula should adapt by itself.

[image]

Change the 10000 reference if need be

For `STDEV` paste the following in `C2` and copy over:

```
=STDEV((INDEX(A:A,ROW()):INDEX(A:A,MATCH(TRUE,INDEX(ISBLANK(INDEX(A:A,ROW()):A$10000),),0)+ROW()-1)))
```

And if you really want to drag the formula down (which is a waiste of CPU) you can put a simple `IF` in front, like so:

```
=IF(OR(A1="",A1="Unit"),<earlier mentioned formulas as a whole>,"")
```